# Get record of only same name person from table

Tags: java, sql, sqlite, inner-join, where-clause

I join two tables with inner join in which we have columns from two tables on same ids primary key of one table and foreign key column of other. How could I get only those record which are having same name of person.

```
public Cursor getMedical() {
    String tables = "SELECT medical.m_id, profiles.name, medical.treatdate,
    medical.medicine, medical.diagnosis FROM profiles INNER JOIN
    medical ON id = id2 where name = ?";
    return mDB.rawQuery(tables,null);
}
```

Comment: my code is not working kindly help me....

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass as an argument, the name. 
You can change the method to this:

```
public Cursor getMedical(String name) {
    String tables = "SELECT medical.m_id, profiles.name, medical.treatdate,
    medical.medicine, medical.diagnosis FROM profiles INNER JOIN
    medical ON id = id2 where name = ?";
    return mDB.rawQuery(tables, new String[] {name});
}
```

The argumnent `name` of the method `getMedical()` will be passed as a parameter to the `rawQuery()` method.
 
Now you can call the method:

```
Cursor c = getMedical("Bob");
```

The `Cursor` `c` now contains all the rows that have in column `name` tha name `"Bob"`.

Comment: If the record of person already exists in table and again inserted record of that person so when I click getRecord button it will give me record of only that person. whose record I am inserting in the table . How could i do that?

Comment: What is the getRecord button and what is all that: *If the record of person already exists in table *? My answer is about the code you posted. If you also have something different to ask post another question.